# Random area covered by disks: what do I need to prove normal covergence?

Tags: probability, geometry, normal-distribution

Consider a square $\mathcal{L}$ of side $L$, a Poisson point process $\mathcal{P} \subset \mathcal{L}$ of expected $n$ points, and unit disks with their centres at the points of $\mathcal{P}$. The disks can overlap with the boundary $\partial \mathcal{L}$.

Let the total area of the square $\mathcal{L}$ covered by the union of the disks be the random variable $\mathcal{A}$.

In the `dense' limit where $n \to \infty$ at fixed $L$, consider the random uncovered area $L^2 - A$. Does this converge somehow to a Gaussian distribution? The area will be small, but random, and so a sort of central limit theorem may well apply.

I imagine I could bound the deviation of $f_{L^2-A}(x)$ from that of the corresponding Gaussian distribution with the same mean and variance as $L^2 - A$. What would I need to prove this? Just bounds on some of the moments of $L^2 - A$?

Below is an image of the square. The area $L^2 - A$ is shown in white.

[image]